# Windows named pipe intermittant connection problems

Tags: winapi, named-pipes

I've got a pair of windows processes that communicate via named pipes. The server calls `CreateNamedPipeW` and the client calls `CreateFileW` to open the same named pipe. Some times this works fine, and then can send messages back and forth. Some times this fails with the error `ERROR_PIPE_BUSY` on both ends.

I'm pretty sure there is exactly one copy of each of the server and client process. I'm also sure that there is exactly one thread on each end that does the pipe management. i.e. I don't think my problem is that there are multiple producers or consumers.

server:

```
OVERLAPPED openServerOverlapped;
...
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
// ...
server = CreateNamedPipeW(
    pipeName.c_str(),
    PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
    PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE | PIPE_WAIT,
    1,
    PIPE_BUFFER_SIZE,
    PIPE_BUFFER_SIZE,
    NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT,
    &sa
);
if (server != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    auto lastError = ConnectNamedPipe(server, &openServerOverlapped) == FALSE
        ? GetLastError()
        : ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED;
    if (lastError == ERROR_IO_PENDING) {
        DWORD bytesTransferred = 0;
        lastError = GetOverlappedResultEx(
            server, &openServerOverlapped, &bytesTransferred,
            CLIENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, FALSE
        ) == FALSE
            ? GetLastError()
            : ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED;
    }
    if (lastError == ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED) {
        // start reading messages
    } else {
        // error handling, looks like "ConnectNamedPipe error..."
    }
} else {
    // error handling, looks like "CreateNamedPipeW error..."
}
```

We sometimes get errors like the following

```
got error: CreateNamedPipeW error: LastError=000000e7, All pipe instances are busy.
```

`e7` is `ERROR_PIPE_BUSY`, which matches the erorr message we got from `FormatMessage`

When this is happening we get similar errors out of our client. Client is actually c#, but uses marshalling to call the same win32 APIs.

client:

```
while (true) {
    // ...
    pipeHandle = CreateFileW(fileName,
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
        IntPtr.Zero,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
        IntPtr.Zero
    );
    if (pipeHandle.ToInt32() == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        // error handling, looks like "Failed to create pipe client..."
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        continue;
    }
    // ...
}
```

We get logging like:

```
Failed to create pipe client, win32 error: 231
```

`231` = `e7`, so same error: `ERROR_PIPE_BUSY`

Comment: Per the `CreateFile` documentation: "*If there is at least one active pipe instance but there are no available listener pipes on the server, **which means all pipe instances are currently connected**, CreateFile fails with ERROR_PIPE_BUSY.*" Make sure the server is calling `DisconnectNamedPipe()` when it is done using the connection established by `ConnectNamedPipe()`. You could optionally also open multiple pipe handles with `CreateNamedPipe()` so you can service multiple clients simultaneously. Also, you should be using `WaitNamedPipe()` on the client side to know when to call `CreateFile()`

Comment: @RemyLebeau the `WaitNamedPipe` is interesting, I somehow missed that function entirely. I'll experiment with that.

One thing that is interesting is that I get that error on the server side sometimes too, on the `CreateNamedPipeW` call. I'm definitely calling `DisconnectNamedPipe` and then `CloseHandle` after an error before I call `CreateNamedPipeW` again. Can you explain the server side behavior too?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation:

[Named Pipe Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/named-pipe-client)

> A named pipe client uses the CreateFile function to open a handle to a named pipe. If the pipe exists but all of its instances are busy, CreateFile returns INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE and the GetLastError function returns ERROR_PIPE_BUSY.

The reason for the error is that all of its instances are busy.

I suggest you try to use the [`CreateNamedPipe()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createnamedpipea) function to create another instance of a named pipe. And also try to use the [`DisconnectNamedPipe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/namedpipeapi/nf-namedpipeapi-disconnectnamedpipe) function to disconnect the server end of a named pipe instance from a client process, and then you can connect that instance to another client by using the `ConnectNamedPipe()` function.

I suggest you refer to the example: [Multithreaded Pipe Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/multithreaded-pipe-server)

Comment: When errors occur my workflow is to:
- call `DisconnectNamedPipe`
- call `CloseHandle` on the pipe handle
- start the process over with `CreateNamedPipeW`

My interpretation of that is that the new pipe should have a new set of clients that can connect to it (1 in this case). Is there any reason I might get this error on `CreateNamedPipeW` after cleaning up behind myself?

Comment: @JeffreyPrice are you calling `DisconnectNamedPipe()` when errors DON'T occur? After calling `DisconnectNamedPipe()`, you can reuse that same `HANDLE` with `ConnectNamedPipe()` again. But, if you want to handle multiple clients simultaneously, you should call `CreateNamedPipe()`, then `ConnectNamedPipe()` until a client connects, then go back to `CreateNamedPipe()` and `ConnectNamedPipe()` so a new client can connect *while* the previous client is being serviced. When a client is finished, call `DisconnectNamedPipe()` and then either close that `HANDLE`, or reuse it with `ConnectNamedPipe()`.

Comment: @JeffreyPrice in other words, you need multiple pipe `HANDLE`s active in the service in order to handle multiple clients simultaneously.

Comment: OK that makes sense. I am intentionally connecting a single client, so I pass 1 as the max instances to CreateNamedPipe. I am disconnecting every time I get any error (e.g. ReadFile or WriteFile). Previously I was also calling CloseHandle after DisconnectNamedPipe, and then starting over with CreateNamedPipe and ConnectNamedPipe. I'm currently experimenting with CreateNamedPipe once at program start and only calling CloseHandle when shutting down, which I think matches your description of how it ought to work.